# Does the Service Layer classes breaks the SRP principle?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, solid-principles

Well, that came to my mind when i was watching a **SOLID** video. The **Single Responsabily Principle** says that "a class should have only a single responsibility".

Thats good. But at the same time, im working in a ASP.NET MVC 5 project architected in N-Layer model. We have the UI layer, the Repository Layer the Domain Layer and the Service Layer to expose. On the Service Layer we have basically one class per **Domain** class (`UserService`, `CompanyService`, etc). The `UserService` class has one responsability that is to take care of the `User` operations, but on the other hand, it has a lot of differents responsabilities like Authentication and deal with that User/Company relationship. Is that a violation of SRP principle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course. In fact, the number of lines of code of that class must be very large, a clear indication of code smell.

When you talk about single responsability you should think in reasons to change. Why my code could change? In the example you put, I can think of several reasons: I decide to change the auth system, the way of my database works, the way I do validation... All of them are clues to make different classes having as results `AuthService`, `UserValidator`, `UsersRepository`...

When you described us what your class does, you used the word "and": "*like Authentication and deal with that User/Company relationship*". That is another symptom of your class is doing too much. If you can't describe the class without using "and" you are probably violating the principle

Although you're firmly convinced that these possibilities of change will not occur because the system will be always well, it's good divide the code because you will have the code better organized and testable.

Answer (score 9):

It violates SRP only if you **put the all multiple-responsibility implementation inside**. In SRP, a class can have one and only one responsibility. Managing user operation is one responsibility, but can be broken to sub-responsibility as well such as `authorization`, `company relation`, etc.

Each sub-responsibility can be implemented as each separated class. Then your UserService will then use those sub-classes together as [aggregate services](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/). eg:

```
public class UserService{
    public UserAuthorizationService UserAuthorizationService = new UserAuthorizationService();
    public UserCompanyRelationService UserCompanyRelationService = new 
UserCompanyRelationService();

    public bool IsAuthorized(){
        // use UserAuthorizationService
    }
    public // whatever you do with UserCompanyRelationService 
}
```

Comment: The userservice will be the facade ,so.

Comment: So it don't break the SRP rule...

Comment: Although this example is SRP compliant, it is still not SOLID compliant, as it violates The Dependency Inversion Principle, using the keyword "new" for hardcoded dependencies. This is not a SOLID example.